# SCP files from machineB to machineA by logging into machineA

Tags: 12.04, files, scp

I am trying to scp the files from `machineB` to `machineA`. I need to run the `scp command` from `machineA` to copy files from `machineB` to `machineA`.

The file that I need to copy from machineB is -

```
/bat/data/snapshot/5.data
```

And where I need to copy the file into machineA is -

```
/data01/primary
```

in which I have root access as well and `/data01/primary` has only root credentials.  Below is the `ls -lt` on `machineA`

```
david@machineA:/$ ls -lt

drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov  7 17:43 data02
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Nov  7 17:42 data01
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov  7 17:26 opt
```

So I was trying the below scp command on machineA to copy the files -

```
scp david@machineB:/bat/data/snapshot/5.data root@machineA:/data01/primary
```

but I am always getting -

```
Host key verification failed.
```

I do have root access to machineA but not root access to machineB. And I can ping machineB from machineA as well. And both machines are in production domain as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` can cause this. You can either remove the file

```
rm -i ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

or you could edit the file and remove the line containing `machine B`.